# iOS removing view

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

I have two views, viewA and viewB. I load viewB on top of viewA with

```
[self.view addSubview: viewB.view];
```

I wan't to remove viewB, but I don't how to do it. I tried

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

but this isn't working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call `-removeFromSuperview` on `viewB.view`.

Comment: tried it, app crashes with this: `-[viewB performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf568d40`

Comment: can you post more of your code? it's hard to know what's going wrong without more context.

Comment: I found out, that the crash wasn't related to that. It work perfectly now.

Comment: Thanx, helped me out to delete my button on button press.

Answer (score 7):

To remove viewB's view from its superview, you need to call removeFromSuperview on that view.

```
[viewB.view removeFromSuperview];
```

From the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

```
removeFromSuperview
```

> Unlinks the receiver from its superview and its window, and removes it
>   from the responder chain.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track by using the removeFromSuperView.  But you need to send the message to the view that you want to remove.  Just as Till example

```
[viewB.view removeFromSuperview];
```

However, you might not have a handle to viewB by the time you want to remove it if you are not using property and synthesize method.  I would make use of @property and @synthesize. So you can use:

```
[self.viewB.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Another way is using this:  (assuming that your viewB.view is the last view you added to viewA.view

```
[[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:(self.view.subviews.count - 1)]removeFromSuperview];
```

You can get a list of all subviews of your viewA by:

```
NSLog(@"subviews of viewA.view: %@",self.view.subviews);
```

Comment: FYI you can call `lastObject` to get the last object of an array (instead of `self.view.subviews.count - 1)`

Comment: I'm adding a lot of things programmatically, so `removeFromSuperview` is my choice.